# Substring search with pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-postgresql, pg-search

I'm using `pg_search` to search for Products:

```
class Product
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope(
    :search_for,
    against: %i(sku),
    associated_against: { translations: [:name, :description] },
    using: { tsearch: { prefix: true } }
  )
end
```

This works fine so far. But I'd like to add the option to search for partial keywords, so customers can find a product that has the sku "123456789" by typing "45678". This would be easy to do with `LIKE`, but can find no way to combine that with `pg_search`, so the results are combined and ranked together.

How can I get `pg_search` to find products by partial strings?

Comment: As far as I know from working with pg_search, the option `prefix: true` you pass should do the work. You can try using `trigram` instead of `tsearch`, as that one searches through triplets of letters instead of whole string

Comment: `prefix: true` only looks for prefixes, so for `12345` I get matches searching for `123`, but not for `234`

Comment: @csch I am facing the same issue now. did you get any solution to it. please help me if you find any solution

Comment: @anusha sorry, this was almost 4 years ago and I don't remember how I ended up solving that issue. I also don't have access to the codebase anymore, so I cannot look it up :-/

Comment: @csch ok, thank you for confirming

Answer (score 1):

PostGres' [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) extension will let you do fuzzy searches inside a string with it's `word_similarity` attribute set to `true`.

1. Generate the migration

```bash
    rails g migration AddPgTrgmExtensionToDB
```

2. Migration file

```rb
    class AddPgTrgmExtensionToDb < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
      def change
        enable_extension 'pg_trgm'
      end
    end
```

3. Define your PG search scope as per [pg_search docs](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#trigram-trigram-search)

```rb
    pg_search_scope :search_for, against: :sku, using: { trigram: { word_similarity: true } }
```